# Subsetting dataframe inside list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have two `pandas.DataFrame` that share some columns. I want to append data from one based on shared information in the other. The problem is that those are pretty huge datasets, and I'll need to run these lines several time with several pairs of tables. For that reason, it needs to be pretty fast.
My dataframe look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

mat = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],'OTHER_ID':[6,7,8,9,10]})
sess= pd.DataFrame({'ID':[11,12,13,14,15],'MAT_ID':[6,7,8,1,2]})
```

I can do what I want using map, like this:

```
sess['NEWCOLUMN']=list(map(lambda x:mat[mat['ID']==x]['OTHER_ID'],sess['MAT_ID']))
```

but I'd like to do it with list comprehension, since it's faster. This is what I've tried:

```
sess['NEWCOLUMN']=[x for x in sess['MAT_ID'] mat[mat['ID']==x]['OTHER_ID']]
```

however, I got a syntax error. I know that I can do it using a regular for loop, but that's not what I'm looking for.
Can I do this with list comprehension, and if so, how?

Comment: Does the 'NEWCOLUMN' is as Series?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Could be a list or a series, as long as I can append in my dataframe, I don't really care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you could use the following list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

mat = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],'OTHER_ID':[6,7,8,9,10]})
sess= pd.DataFrame({'ID':[11,12,13,14,15],'MAT_ID':[6,7,8,1,2]})

sess['NEWCOLUMN']= [mat[mat['ID']==x]['OTHER_ID'] for x in sess['MAT_ID']]
print(sess)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use map without a loop

```
sess['NEWCOLUMN'] = sess['MAT_ID'].map(mat.set_index('OTHER_ID').ID)


    ID  MAT_ID  NEWCOLUMN
0   11  6       1.0
1   12  7       2.0
2   13  8       3.0
3   14  1       NaN
4   15  2       NaN
```